# Deployed Silverlight wcf service causes an error

Tags: wcf, silverlight

I have seen many threads related to this but I still can't solve this problem. I have a silverlight busiless application in which I have a silverlight enabled wcf service added. Everything works fine on the developement server but when I deploy the application on ISS7 on same machine, when I access the service I get an error

An exception occurred during the operation, making the result invalid.  Check InnerException for exception details.

at System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs.RaiseExceptionIfNecessary()
   at QTMS.QTMSWcfService.GetTestArtifactHierarchyCompletedEventArgs.get_Result()
   at QTMS.Views.AutomationStatus.QTMSWcfServiceProxy_GetTestArtifactHierarchyCompleted(Object sender, GetTestArtifactHierarchyCompletedEventArgs TestArtifactsList)
   at QTMS.QTMSWcfService.QTMSWcfServiceClient.OnGetTestArtifactHierarchyCompleted(Object state)

Here's my web.config content

Here's the content of the ServiceReferences.ClientConfig file

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <customBinding>
            <binding name="CustomBinding_QTMSWcfService">
                <binaryMessageEncoding />
                <httpTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" />
            </binding>
        </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:9702/QTMSWcfServices/QTMSWcfService.svc"
            binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="CustomBinding_QTMSWcfService"
            contract="QTMSWcfService.QTMSWcfService" name="CustomBinding_QTMSWcfService" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

I can't resolve the following

•Why is the service not working when deployed? I tried to put the clientaccesspolicy.xml in the /bin folder and also in the folder where svc file sits, but that did not help.I also changed the endpoint address to point to the ip of my machine. 
•How do I see the content of inner exception?
•How to check if my  wcf service is running?
By the way, my wcfservice return a custom object and makes a database connection in each function call which i close.

I just can't seem to get it to work. Please help! I can provide more details if required.

Answer (score 0):

What's in the InnerException of that exception?

If you watch the traffic with Fiddler, what do you see? (May need to switch to textMessageEncoding instead of binaryMessageEncoding for Fiddler to be useful)

Does your service get called? (Do you see a request to the .svc in the IIS logs? If so, it's not a cross-domain issue).

Is there anything in the Event Log added at the time of the failed request?

Comment: Thanks EugeneOS. Fiddler helped. It was a problem with the redirection that was happening due to session. Our IIS is configure in such a way that the url has format like  http://<IPAddress>/Silverlightapp/(S(oirppxrwzhlf2a2vbia1ui45))/Default.aspx#/Home

So I had to install the service on another iis server where I could give endpoint address as http://<IPAddress>/Silverlightapp/MyService.svc. This solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It was a client access policy issue, it need to be in the web project file before I published it.